# Do not know how to center lists with bullets attached using no css

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have scoured the internet for an answer to this question but haven't found anything to answer my question.  The problem is that I want to center a ul with bulleted lists using only bootstrap and bootstrap classes and no other css into the center of my page.  I've tried applying classes like text-center and text-block and other things but to no avail.

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul>
        <li><strong>1857</strong>- Birth of Arthur Reuel Tolkien, Tolkien’s father,                                                                         in Birmingham.</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not possible... How in the world do you plan on changing the style with no CSS?

Comment: Bootstrap has its own classes with pre-detrmined styles and jQuery associated with it.  I have made my webpage completely with no css except for a margin-top 100px.

Comment: "I have made my webpage completely with no css except for a margin-top 100px" and soon for your list styles...

Answer (score 1):

I know you want to use only bootstrap, however to my knowledge that is not possible, however you can add an inline style `list-style-position: inside;` to the `ul` that will fix your problem. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c9vuaxrs/

```
<div class="text-center">
    <ul style="list-style-position: inside;">
        <li><strong>1857</strong>- Birth of Arthur Reuel Tolkien, Tolkien’s father,                                                                         in Birmingham.</li>
        <li>Item2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @thinnling if you go to https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css and CTRL+F then look for `list-style-position` you will see it does not exist in bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

@Adam Buchanan Smith Ok, figured it out.  I just had to use .container > .row > 12-columns-grid with offsets.  Thanks for the help. And you can just use html with bootstrap but only with the predefined classes to achieve most results.  Just a reference for you if you ever need to do something like this with bootstrap :)